# Is there a separate FindBugs plug-in for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, static-analysis, findbugs, intellij-plugin

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FindBugs), [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) supports several IDEs as a plug-in, including IntelliJ-Idea, on which Droidio ([Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/studio.html)) is based.

So does this mean that the [IntelliJ-Idea plug-in](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3847) can be installed into Droidio, or is there a distinct one somewhere (or there isn't one yet, but one will be needed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer probably comes a bit late as Droidio is officially called Android Studio by now, and we're already at beta version 0.8.2, but I've just checked that installing the regular FindBugs-IDEA plugin works fine.

Also, I'm not aware of a distinct version of the plugin specifically for Android Studio, which would sort of defeat the purpose of basing Android Studio on IntelliJ IDEA if you had to adapt all IDEA plugins.

Comment: It doesn't work on my machine -- plugin crashes Android Studio on startup, saying that Class Version 51.0 is not supported.  I do have Java 1.7 installed (and building Android Studio projects), so not sure why this is occurring and what the workaround would be.

Comment: Bloody hell...after a month I've finally found the setting to enable it.  See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under.  Check your current JVM version using Android Studio...About Android Studio

Answer (score 5):

There are QAPlug plugins to manage code quality using PMD, Checkstyle and Findbugs.

Ref: http://qaplug.com/

They are also compatible for android studio.

Ref: http://qaplug.com/blog/qaplug-for-android-studio/

To add the QA plugins to android studio;

1-) Click File --> Setings

2-) Select 'Plugins' option from left menu.

3-) Click 'Browse repositories' button.

4-) Write 'QAPLug' keyword in the textbox which is searching plugin.

You will see QAPlug plugins like Checkstyle, FindBugs, Hammurapi and PMD..

5-) Select plugins whichever you want and install them.

6-) Click 'Apply' button and restart android studio.

You are ready to use plugins which are selected by your side.

To use these plugins;

7-) Select your code block or files which have your codes and Right Click -->  Analyze --> Analyze Code

8-) At last, Click 'OK' button.

Selected plugins work and show you code analysis results on Analysis Tab.

More : https://qaplug.com/tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

an update in case anybody bumps into this thread like me...
here's the plugin link. 
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3847?pr=idea

for linux I just extracted the zip file in my android-studio/plugin/ folder and restarted my IDE. After the restart you could see the findbug menu by right clicking a resource.